# Updating a vector of vectors stored in a map

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap

I have a following design in `a.h`:

```
class A {
     virtual void updateCoefficients(std::string /*state*/, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& /*coefs*/,
                                    double /*reward*/) {}
protected: 
     std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<double>>> heuristic;
}

class B : public A {
     virtual void updateCoefficients(std::string state, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& coefs,
                                   double reward) override;
}
```

and in `a.cc`:

```
void B::updateCoefficients(std::string state, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& coefs,
                                   double reward) {
     for(unsigned i = 0; i < coefs.size(); i++) {
         coefs[i][0] += 1;
     }

     for(unsigned i = 0; i < coefs.size(); i++) {
         coefs[i][1] += 2;
     }
}
```

while I call `updateCoefficients` from a method defined in `class A`:

```
void A::foo(std::string state, std::string action, double const& reward) {
        if (heuristic.count(action)) {
            updateCoefficients(state, heuristic[action], reward);
        } else {
            std::vector<std::vector<double>> coefs(20, std::vector<double>(2, 0.0));
            heuristic[action] = coefs;
    } 
}
```

The problem is that the vector `coefs` in the map `heuristic` is not being updated but whenever `updateCoefficients` is called, all the vectors are 0s as they are when they are initialized. What am I doing wrong?

The idea is to have `class A` as a base that contains all the methods and variables that have to be used and to define different `updateCoefficients` methods in child classes that inherit the base from `class A`.

**EDIT**

OK, so the whole code can be found here [OfflineHeuristic.h](https://gist.github.com/DjoleR/e9a80c65dd2ecff7925c546adaeb9888) and [OfflineHeuristic.cc](https://gist.github.com/DjoleR/08288361ccb5a28968e16f6f4e33de68). Information in classes `State`, `ActionState`, `THTS` are irrelevant. I've tried the possible fixes but still, map `heuristic` is constantly filled with zero values. The method that's being called from other classes is `offlineHeuristic->learn(state, action, reward)`.

**EDIT 2**

The error was actually in another place, in the code logic. Making the code pasted above actually correct. I'll leave the question in case anyone run into a problem like that. Or, if that is not a good thing to do, please let me know so I delete the question.

Comment: you'll need to post an MCVE. We have no idea what's going on in the rest of the code.

Comment: @ĐorđeRelić I can only repeat RichardHodges, you need to post an (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example]. The whole code is hardy "minimal". To make it MCVE is your job, not ours.

Comment: @ĐorđeRelić, unfortunately, we are not debugging the code here. If its hard to you using GDB from command line - try some IDE (QTCreator is free and can work without QT, CLion is also good choise...). You should give us some minimal example that can be copy-pasted and run with no changes - and we will help, and the best is to use some online compiler like IdeOne

Comment: @Evgeniy I found the error, it was somewhere else in the code, not connected with code I attached. Debugging helped :) Thanks for your time and sorry for turning this into a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why heuristic  is not updated is because you need to call A::foo twice. First call it will be initialized with zero, and only the next call will update them;

So may be changing code like this will be a solution:

```
void A::foo(std::string state, std::string action, double const& reward) {
      if (!heuristic.count(action)) {
            std::vector<std::vector<double>> coefs(20, std::vector<double>(2, 0.0));
            heuristic[action] = coefs;
      } 
      updateCoefficients(state, heuristic[action], reward);
}
```

And the rest of your code works - data is updated. You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/JDzRRr)

```
A* instance = new B();
instance->foo("aaa", "bbb", 123);
cout << "First call" << endl;

for (auto h : instance->heuristic)
    for (auto b : h.second)
        for (auto c : b)
            cout << c << " ";
cout << endl;               
instance->foo("aaa", "bbb", 123);
cout << "Second call" << endl;

for (auto h : instance->heuristic)
    for (auto b : h.second)
        for (auto c : b)
            cout << c << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Output:

```
First call
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Updated
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: Yes, this is a mistake made by me but it's not the reason why `heuristic` is not being updated. Thanks for pointing to a different mistake I had :)

Comment: @ĐorđeRelić, Debugger will help you :)  I have updated my answer - try it online

Comment: I really hate using GDB so I do a lot of "std::cout <<" debugging and what I concluded is that in while in the method, the values in vectors are being updated but when I enter the method again, they are 0s, like if I was working on another vector. I updated my question with full code in case I made mistakes while simplifying the problem.

Comment: @ĐorđeRelić In this answer, heuristic totally *is* updated. Again, the updating code works just fine, foo is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're using base class method, make it pure virtual to avoid errors. `virtual void updateCoefficients( ... ) = 0;`

Working as expected.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class A {
     virtual void updateCoefficients(std::string /*state*/, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& /*coefs*/,
                                    double /*reward*/) = 0;
protected: 
     std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<double>>> heuristic;
public:
     void foo(std::string state, std::string action, double const& reward);
     virtual ~A() {}

};

void A::foo(std::string state, std::string action, double const& reward) {
        if (heuristic.count(action)) {
            updateCoefficients(state, heuristic[action], reward);
            std::cout << "exist\n";
            std::cout << heuristic[action][0][0] << '\n';
            std::cout << heuristic[action][0][1] << '\n';
        } else {
            std::vector<std::vector<double>> coefs(20, std::vector<double>(2, 0.0));
            heuristic[action] = coefs;
            std::cout << "not exist\n";
    } 
} 

class B : public A {
     virtual void updateCoefficients(std::string state, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& coefs,
                                   double reward) override;
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};

void B::updateCoefficients(std::string state, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& coefs,
                                   double reward) {
     for(unsigned i = 0; i < coefs.size(); i++) {
         coefs[i][0] += 1;
         coefs[i][1] += 2;
     }
}

int main()
{
  A* a = new B();
  a->foo("aaa", "bbb", 2.0);
  a->foo("aaa", "bbb", 2.0);
  a->foo("aaa", "bbb", 2.0);
  delete a;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your fix but it didn't help. I updated the question with links to header and source files on gist, in case I made a mistake in simplifying the code in the first place.

Comment: @ĐorđeRelić add debug print to updateCoefficients method, be sure that you call necessary method. Check everywhere that you use refs.

Comment: I did. As you can see in `GradualDescent::updateCoefficients` there is `SystemUtils::log` on several places and this is the log created: [log](https://gist.github.com/DjoleR/0ac38b002e6f7cee0fdf7ea7573600b7). The old value is always 0 even though it should be only in the first update. So the logic is "Old value"  value  (0|1), last depending on the index in the vector inside the vector which has 2 elements only.

Comment: @ĐorđeRelić `double OfflineHeuristic::calculateSumOfMultipliers(std::vector<std::vector<double>> coefficients, std::vector<double> stateValues)` use ref here &coef

Comment: @ĐorđeRelić add logging to second for loop in updateCoefficients method

Comment: the error was in the 'step back' I was making which always evaluated to true so basically it turned out that every time I add a value, I take it back so the coefficients were altered twice basically canceling every change. Thank you for your time and effort trying to help me!

Comment: @ĐorđeRelić yes, I assume this when ask logging in previous comment.